# Removing hyphens in form data in DataPower gateway

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower, apiconnect, apic, ibm-api-connect

we are trying to pass a file in form data but we are unable to remove the hyphens, Content-Disposition and Content-Type.

```
----------------------------376203720009485735911622
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="Sample.xml"
Content-Type: application/xml

<Root>
<Name> Naruto </Name>
<Occupation> Hokage </Occupation>
</Root>
----------------------------376203720009485735911622--
```

Comment: I am reading input as a buffer using ReadAsBuffer in gateway script.

Answer (score 0):

Your file does not contain valid XML. It contains a multipart HTTP payload with one part of type XML, but everything related to the multipart format must be stripped away before you can feed this into an XSLT processor:

- all lines up to and including the first blank line
- the last line (starting with hyphens).

Comment: I have been trying to delete those but iam unable to remove those multipart payload, guide me to do so in gatewayscript.
Note: those multipart payload is automatically added when i tried to send the sample file(which is an xml file) to the backend server.